# auto populate the account record field value

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, javascript

I have a custom object 'X', while creating a new record in object 'X' there a lookup field related to account object, when i select any account name 'Vinay' then the 'vinay' related account record field should be auto-filled in the 'X' object like email,phone,billingCity? how to achieve this?

Comment: is it ok with you that after saving the X object record with only selecting the account, it should automatically populate???

Comment: no i want to pre populate the account fields after selecting the the account id from the look up in the 'X' object before saving the record.

Comment: @sanketkumar no i want to pre populate the account fields after selecting the the account id from the look up in the 'X' object before saving the record.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to edit those field values then You can use Formula fields and use the formula like below

```
Account__r.Phone
```

if You want to edit these fields after saving the record then **Go For Process Builder OR workflow** to update the Field values in Object X from Account. To update the fields formula will be same as above

```
Account__r.Phone
```

The criteria for Process Builder will be **Account Not Null**

> Note: - Use the Correct API name and Use Insert Field option to Select
>   the Field

Comment: i have 10 fields which should be auto filled by selecting an account record. by using formula fields can we auto fill all that 10 fields at a time?

Comment: that all fields should be auto populated while selecting an account record in look up